# Bulk Uploading Candidate Documents in Salesforce

Tags: salesforce

I'm relatively new to Salesforce and have recently set up an Applicant Tracking System (ATS) within the platform. Currently, I'm looking for a solution to bulk upload various documents associated with candidates into Salesforce, including JPEGs, PDFs, DOCX files, and others.

Could anyone recommend a tool or add-on that would streamline this process for me? I'm particularly interested in something user-friendly and efficient.

Your insights and recommendations would be greatly appreciated!

I've been using Salesforce Inspector Reloaded for importing and exporting data, but unfortunately, it doesn't offer functionality for importing documents.